# Maintain URL and show a subdomain page instead

Tags: .htaccess

I have this URL I need to maintain for SEO purposes: http://vivilondra.it/servizio-taxi.html

This HTML page uses an iframe to display the content of a subdomain page: http://shop.vivilondra.it/servizio-taxi

I would delete this HTML but preserve maintain the URL in the browser.
There is any way through the htaccess to show the URL http://vivilondra.it/servizio-taxi.html showing the content of http://shop.vivilondra.it/servizio-taxi?

Comment: Which folder is your subdomain pointing to?

Comment: Certainly that is possible. Easiest would be to setup a "reverse proxy", so use the ProxyPass directive. Take a look at the modules documentation, it comes with good examples.

Answer (score 0):

> There is any way through the htaccess to show the URL
>   http://vivilondra.it/servizio-taxi.html showing the content of
>   http://shop.vivilondra.it/servizio-taxi?

Use `mod_proxy` in combination with `mod_rewrite` via the [P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html http://shop.vivilondra.it/$1 [P]
```